# Combine multiple click handlers into one

Tags: javascript, jquery

Say I have two click handlers which perform the same functionality :

```
$('#div1').click(function(event) {  
alert('here');                              
});

$('#div2').click(function(event) {  
alert('here');                              
});
```

How can I combine these two handlers into one instead of repeating the call to alert ?

Something like :

```
$('#div1').click.('#div2').click(function(event) {  
alert('here');                              
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('#div1, #div2').click(function(event) {  
   alert('here');                              
});
```

Furthermore, if you have a lot of `div` elements, contained in a common parent, you may take benefit of event delegation and attach a single handler to the parent itself, like so:

```
$('.common-parent').on('click', 'div', function(event) {  
   ...                          
});
```

Answer (score 4):

First way :

```
$('#div1, #div2').click(function(event) {  
     alert('here');                              
});
```

Second way :

```
function doIt(e) {
    alert('here');
}
$('#div1').click(doIt);
$('#div2').click(doIt);
```

Note that the fact you have this problem sometimes means you should use a class and not just id, so that you may do something like

```
$('.alertable').click(function(event) {  
     alert('here');                              
});
```